# Retrieve Color from Plist. iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, plist, uicolor

I am trying to Retrieve a UIColor from my plist in a dictionary but am having some trouble doing this.

I added my UIColors in my plist in a dictionary and then in strings. (See attached image)

i am saving them like so in my plist :

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:57/255.0 green:131/255.0 blue:50/255.0 alpha:1]
```

Then I have a file Where I save all my colours like:

```
+ (instancetype)titleBarColor
{
return [UIColor colorWithRed:57/255.0 green:131/255.0 blue:50/255.0 alpha:1];
}
```

but I would like to do something like :

```
+ (instancetype)titleBarColor
{

NSBundle* settings = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSMutableDictionary *testing = [settings objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"appColours"];
UIColor *test = [testing objectForKey:@"titleBarColor"];
NSLog(@"Test Colour %@", test);
return test;
}
```

But obviously get a crash due to the color being picked up by a string.

Comment: Store them as a string hex value

Comment: `UIColor` instances can not be stored directly into property lists. Only instances of `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSDate` and (possibly nested) dictionaries/arrays of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I store them as hex values and then use the following to retrieve:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString andAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha {

    //If non valid string:
    if (!hexString)
        return nil;

    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:alpha];
}
```

Or simply save the float values separated by a comma and parse it out. There's a few solutions ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Swift 3 / iOS 10 Version of CW0007007's answer:

```
extension UIColor{
    static func colorFrom(hexString:String, alpha:CGFloat = 1.0)->UIColor{
        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexString)
        scanner.scanLocation = 1 // bypass # character
        scanner.scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)
        let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0
        let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8)/255.0
        let blue = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x0000FF) >> 8)/255.0
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```